# How can I create view in SQL Server Compact?

Tags: sql, view, sql-server-ce

How can I create view in SQL Server Compact? Or is it possible to create view in SQl Server Compact?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create views in SQL Server Compact, you must create the SELECT statement in code instead.